# How to route a VoIP call in FusionPBX?

Tags: sip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have just installed FusionPBX but I couldn't figure out how to route a call coming form a server to another server.

I have a receiving server Z, its IP, prefix, dial string, G.729, SIP. Another server X wants to send calls to my server Y and my server Y has to route that call to server Z.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the IP address of the other server to Advanced -> Access Controls and edit the domains access control. Leave the domains to default deny and add a new node with CIDR set to the IP address of the other server followed by /32 with type set to allow. Then go to Status -> SIP Status and press the Reload ACL button. Now you can setup an Inbound Route using Dialplan -> Destinations with the number that is being called.